# I'm always vs I'll always

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is it correct to say:

> "As a fan, **I'm** always going to support him."

Or, should I just use this:

> "As  a fan, **I'll** always going to support him."

And, is it redundant to use going to in the sentences above?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the famous soundtrack of the movie *Bodyguard*. Is

> I will always love you

the same with

> I am always going to love you?

There is a difference in register but also in intention. I think ***I will always support*** is stronger and less casual than ***I am always going to support you***.

Answer (score 1):

"I will always going to support him" sounds completely wrong to English ears.

"I will always support him," implies that there is nothing that could be done to stop that support.

"I am always going to support him," conveys the same meaning.

The difference in these sentences is that the first is *future perfect* tense - as if it's already happened.
The second is *future imperfect* - you're going to do it but it isn't done yet. In this case as a thing you will continue to do. This mode may also mean something you'll do once - for example, "I am going to clean my room," where cleaning has a definite point at which it will end but supporting someone does not.

"I support him," is less committed - you support him now but that could change. The use of "always" strengthens the commitment in these sentences.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, that is correct.
2. *I'll [I will] always support him* is sufficient. *I am going to* is a less formal way of saying that you will do something.